# jQuery.when: What happens if one function fails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the next javascript function which executes four ajax functions and later, if they have all the status `200` proceed to execute a new call.

I was wondering what happens if one of those four AJAX calls fails, the one inside the jQuery.done also gets executed?

```
$.when(
   ajax1(), 
   ajax2(), 
   ajax3(), 
   ajax4())
 .done(function(a1, a2, a3, a4) {
    if(a1[2].status === 200 && a2[2].status === 200 && 
       a3[2].status === 200 && a4[2].status === 200) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/whatever",
            data: { 
                var1: a1[2].responseText,
                var2: a2[2].responseText,
                var3: a3[2].responseText,
                var4: a4[2].responseText
            },
            success: function(){
                alert("Success");
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("Error");
    }
}
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: If i get your problem right; you can pass a wrong url to one of those ajax calls and see the result. I think it is better to see results yourself when you have a chance.

Comment: Each of your ajax functions should fail themselves if they fail and don't return a 200 status code, and your `alert` code should be in a `.fail()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> In the multiple-Deferreds case where one of the Deferreds is rejected, jQuery.when() immediately fires the failCallbacks for its master Deferred

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: Shame on me that I didn't saw this on the docs. Thank you Rory!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.